# Do any phones other than the Samsung S have gyroscope capabilities?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

The Samsung S, Android's first official phone to support 2.3 will have gyroscoping capabilities. Do any other phones have a gyroscope?

Comment: This one's a good question, specific and objective :)

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung Galaxy S series phones have a 6-axis accelerometer, which is not a true gyroscope although a good approximation.  Hopefully it is actually a true gyroscope in the Nexus S.  Motorola's next big phone is rumored to have a gyroscope, but who knows.  I don't believe any other Android phones have a gyroscope, but the iPhone 4 does.

Comment: so the iphone4 is 2.3 compliant, awesome.

Comment: Well the iPhone 4 does use a processor made by Samsung that is very similar to the Snapdragon used in the Nexus S. Overall it's practically begging to be an Android phone!

Answer (score 1):

After a little search I've found the following Android devices with built in gyroscope:

- HTC Sensation
- Samsung Google Nexus S
- Samsung Galaxy S2
- Samsung Galaxy R
- LG Electronics P990 Optimus Speed

Can't say anything about whether they have a true gyroscope or not

Answer (score 0):

Most Android phones from the original G1 upwards have an accelerometer (often called the G-Sensor in HTC phones) and compass inbuilt which performs the same job. There's very little you'd get from a true gyroscope that these don't offer you.

Comment: You actually need a gyroscope and an accellerometer to fully sense motion.

Comment: Accelerometers cannot detect rotation.  And what about motions at constant (or near-constant) speed?

Comment: My only true (and deep) interest in this is first person shooters. Nova 2 and Modern Combat 2 on iphone are just too awesome. I wish I had a gyroscope on my Acer Liquid Metal :(